# Should I add polyfills to my angular project for IE11 when using differential loading in local development mode?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I've upgraded a project of mine to Angular 8 and differential-loading is enabled now. For production builds everything works fine, In Internet Explorer 11 the ES5 bundles are used and in Chrome the ES2015 bundles are used. In development mode, the ES2015 target is used and therefore it is not possible to view the project in Internet Explorer, because Internet Explorer does not support ES2015 features.

Now I want to view my project in development mode in IE11 and I've followed the instructions from [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#local-development-in-older-browsers) and I think my local build is now using the ES5 target, because instead of Syntax Errors, I now see other errors related to missing polyfills in my browser console. Adding the polyfills (for example Promise from core-js) fixed the issues, but now I've added new polyfills to my polyfills.ts file, while they weren't needed for the production builds. Apparently for production builds the correct polyfills were already automatically added.

Should I add the polyfills to my polyfills.ts file, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the Angular CLI?